Puffer data for live-plotting via pyqtgraph
I have an dataframe, i import this dataframe in an python modul and then i plott them live. Each dataframe has 100 numbers. For this i use pyqtgraph:
  def update_plot_data(self):
        from safe_to_excel import df
        spo2_list = df['Red'].tail(SAMPE_ARRAY).astype(float)  # Gibt die letzten 100 Werte aus
        spo2_list.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # Setze den Index zurück

        index = 0  # Startindex für den Datenabruf
        while index < SAMPE_ARRAY:
            data_point = spo2_list[index]  # Datenpunkt für den aktuellen Index

            print(f"Datenpunkt {index + 1}: {data_point}")  # Datenpunkt printen

            self.data = np.roll(self.data, -1)
            self.data[-1] = data_point
            self.plot_item.setData(y=self.data)  # Aktualisieren der Daten des Plot-Items

            pg.QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()  # Aktualisieren des Plot-Widgets
            time.sleep(0.017)  # Pause von 10 Millisekunden

            index += 1

        # Nachdem alle 100 Datenpunkte abgearbeitet wurden
        # Aktualisiert das DataFrame `df` und ladet neue Daten
        from safe_to_excel import df
        spo2_list = df['Red'].tail(SAMPE_ARRAY).astype(float)  # Gibt die letzten 100 Werte aus
        spo2_list.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # Setze den Index zurück

        index = 0  # Setze den Index auf 0 für den nächsten Durchlauf

The Code here works, but the transitions from one array to the other are not perfect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSYTVeHccgg&t=3s How can i fix this? I think i need an puffer? Maybe i should use a second list and add each 100 number sample to this list, then i make a new list with 100 datapoints to plott, after i plott them i take the next 100 sampels from the puffer list?
I have tried difference ways with lists, but at the moment no solution works.

from what i understand (correct me if i am wrong): the df gets filled somewhere else while the data is plotted. you are only using its most recent 100 datapoints. during plotting, more than 100 datapoints are generated. so when plotting the next 100 points, you are missing some datapoints, which leads to imperfect transisitions, correct? What is your data acquisition rate? do you want it to be in sync with your plotting rate? What about triggering the plotting function whenever there is new data available, e.g. via a thread?

1:
Yes, right. I have an libary for this, there i write data in an data frame an this i import in this script. I write 100 numbers with 50 sampels per seconds in this. The data i send from an esp32 via ble to the PC_python app.
2:
"so when plotting the next 100 points, you are missing some datapoints" yes
3:
" do you want it to be in sync with your plotting rate? " yes
4:
"What about triggering the plotting function" In the first version a timer, now i will try a other way

Here is my next try:
https://github.com/ImmanuelT8/Smart-Health-8/blob/main/2024/verkn%C3%BCpfung_des_filters/4/4/live_plotter.py
Here i have an QThread to handle the import for the data an add to a list.
In the line 156 it will print correct 1 array after the next "
"if self.data_to_plot_IR: print("Daten zum Plotten:", self.data_to_plot_IR)"
But i can't plott them at the moment correct.

You next try is close to what I would be going for, but I would directly "consume" the new data once available instead of creating intermittent buffers.
Here's a minimal example to illustrate this approach:
import random

from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject, QRunnable ,QThreadPool ,QTimer ,pyqtSignal
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    result = pyqtSignal(list)



# This thread constantly looks for new data in the <data> list
class Consumer(QRunnable):
    signals = WorkerSignals()

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.previous_length = len(data)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if (current_length := len(self.data)) <= self.previous_length:
                continue  # no new data available, try again
            new_data = self.data[self.previous_length:]
            self.signals.result.emit(new_data)
            self.previous_length = current_length


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.data = []

        # generate data every 100ms (can be changed arbitrarily)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.generate)
        self.timer.start(100)

        consumer = Consumer(self.data)
        consumer.signals.result.connect(self.consume)
        self.threadpool.start(consumer)

        self.show()

    # this method is called whenever new data is available
    def consume(self, s):
        print("NEW DATA:", s)

    def generate(self):
        self.data.append(random.randint(0, 100))


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()

